# Use xpath in importhtml

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to get from product hunt the upvotes into a google spreadsheet.

I tried the following:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A2,"//section[@class='post-vote-button--count']/text()")
```

`A2` is in my case `https://www.producthunt.com/tech/i-brew-my-own-coffee`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMPORTHTML` only allows you to find either lists or tables. `IMPORTXML` would allow you to use a general XPath expression.

The `IMPORTXML` function is actually intended for reading in XML data, not HTML. But if the HTML is XHTML or reasonable HTML, you can use `IMPORTXML` to import HTML data and then apply an XPath expression to it.

In this case, the HTML is not well-formed enough to be parsed by the `IMPORTXML` function and `IMPORTHTML` does not allow you to find the content you are interested in.

So, as far as I know: there is no way to achieve what you want - except writing custom code for Google Sheets.

---

**EDIT**: The comments above are an incorrect analysis of the OP's specific problem, as pointed out by Aurielle Perlmann. In fact, this formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.producthunt.com/tech/i-brew-my-own-coffee","//span[@class='post-vote-button--count']")
```

or the one of Aurielle will work. In the HTML source, "166" - the wanted result - is not inside a `section` element, but a `span` element. Here is a snippet of the page source:

```
<span class="post-vote-button--count" 
      data-reactid=".2dbdvned0xs.0.0.0.2.1.1">166</span>
```

Additionally, it seems that using `text()` in an XPath expression in Google Sheets is buggy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! How would you write custome code? Could you lay out a short concept? How could I reach this tag without knowing it`s specific path via `xpath`?

Comment: @mrquad You should seriously consider whether this is worth the effort. By "custom code" I meant developing a [Sheets add-on with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/). _"How could I reach this tag without knowing its specific path via xpath`?"_ I don't really know what you mean by that - reading your question, I have the impression that you already _know_ the specific path of this item. Writing custom code would mean extending Google Sheets with functionality that allows you to parse HTML and use this path expression.

Comment: @mrquad Also, this is only a suggestion, I do not know what is actually possible with the Apps Script platform.

Comment: see below - it absolutely achievable with importxml instead of custom code

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann You are right, my answer is wrong. The problem actually is that "166" is not inside a `section` element, but a `span` element. Thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull it with this xpath:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.producthunt.com/tech/i-brew-my-own-coffee","//*[@class='post-vote-button--count']")
```